# 3D Nav CSS3 Rotate Transform Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a 3d navbar and running into issues with one of my CSS rules not doing anything, yet a rule with similar precedence seems to be working fine.

This 1 isn't working:

```
#main-navbar.hover-home .bottom li:nth-child(1) {
     transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(25px);
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/LshqLfo2/3/) is a fiddle demonstrating the issue.

I've updated my fiddle to include the transition effect, you can see the `.front li:nth-child(1)` is rotating just fine, but the `.bottom li:nth-child(1)` does not move.

These are the classes that control the rotate:

```
//works
#main-navbar.hover-home .front li:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(25px);
}
//not working
#main-navbar.hover-home .bottom li:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(25px);
}
```

I'm trying to get the `.bottom` part of the nav to also rotate at the same time as the .`front`

Comment: AFAIK you're not using that function correctly... http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Maybe try changing your fiddle and show what is working and what exactly you are trying to achieve, that line isn't working because your JQuery is handling mouse enter event on selector '.front' not '.bottom'

Comment: both events are supposed to trigger on `mouseenter` for the `.front li:nth-child(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouseenter event on second(.bottom) li is not triggering because front UL overlapping it you need to change HTML structure. check out this fiddle:

```
<nav id="main-navbar">        
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#">
            <span class="front">Home</span>
            <span class="bottom">Home</span></a>
          </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>        
  </nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ashish1bhagat/LshqLfo2/4/